# How can django order a queryset such that specific instances are listed first?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to order my queryset in such a way:

```
>>tag_queryset
[tag4, tag3, tag1, tag2]
```

Default queryset is:

```
>>Tag.objects.all()
[tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4]
```

So I have a specific queryset like:

```
 >>tags_to_place_first
 [tag4, tag3]
```

And I want to merge it with the common queryset of all() objects in Tag model to place tag4 and tag3 first in the resulting sequence:

```
#something like this
>>Tag.objects.all().placeFirst(tags_to_place_first)
[tag4, tag3, tag1, tag2]
```

Can anyone give a good solution for this that does not hinder performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a **performance** solution, then, the approach is that. For your tag model **append a new property named 'sort_field'**:

```
from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sort_field = models.IntegerField()
```

Populate model as your convenience:

```
Tab.objects.filter( name = 'tag4' ).update( sort_field = 1 )
Tab.objects.filter( name = 'tag3' ).update( sort_field = 2 )
```

Finally **sort by new sort_field**:

```
Tag.objects.all().order_by( 'sort_field' )
```

Comment: Might be even worse if `tags_to_place_first` is big and he updates the `sort_field` one by one.

Answer (score -1):

You can merge querysets like:

```
merged_tags_qs = tags_to_place_first | other_tags
```

valid for lists or single instances:

```
merged_tags_qs = [tag4, tag3] | other_tags
merged_tags_qs = tag4 | other_tags
```

It's one of the django's magic features :D

If you want to remove the tags in `tags_to_place_first` from the queryset:

```
other_tags = Tag.objects.exclude(pk__in=[tag.pk for tag in tags_to_place_first])
merged_tags_qs = tags_to_place_first | other_tags
```

Comment: I have tags_to_place_first already there in other_tags, does not work. i tried before asking.

Comment: @Feanor I don't understand the problem. Do you want to remove the elements in `tags_to_place_first` from `other_tags` to avoid duplicates?

Comment: i think i wrote very clearly what i have and what i expect in resulting queryset. I want a part of queryset to be placed in first position in the bigger queryset that already contains it.

Comment: oh.. do you ever try the code you suggest? tags_to_place_first is a queryset, not a list of ids, even though right exclude is: Tag.objects.exclude(id__in=[o.id for o in tags_to_place_first])

Comment: @Feanor ?? I don't need to... I've merged querysets like this quite often. What you're requesting is not something that you should need to do though. You might want to rethink your implementation